# File transfer (File.Move() ) unexpected behavior

Tags: c#, file, file-transfer

Im trying to move a file from one location to another.

```
        private void SendFileToDestination()
        {
            string file = "HATKANOT_BETIHOT_231230.txt";

            string sourceFilePath = Path.Combine(@"FTPUSERS\hoz_tbr\from\", file);

            string destinationFilePath = Path.Combine(@"C:\ARCHIVE\dgamim\CompanyC\", file);

            File.Copy(sourceFilePath, destinationFilePath);
        }
```

Ive hardcoded the paths since I was trying to overcome the issue Im going to detail below, but, the issue kept occuring.

So, the issue is that I get this error:

System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path 'E:\GalWorkspace\workspace\SlikaNetCore\Dgamim\bin\Debug\net8.0\FTPUSERS\hoz_tbr\from\HATKANOT_BETIHOT_231230.txt'.'

Im not sure why its looking under the entire E:\GalWorkspace\workspace\SlikaNetCore\Dgamim\bin\Debug\net8.0
as I never mentioned it in my code.
What am I missing?

I was obviously expecting it to be transfered from one hardcoded location to another.

Comment: You're using a relative path, `FTPUSERS\hoz_tbr\from\file`, this will be relative to *something*, which, depending on how you start the process, can be the folder where the executable is located. If you are talking about a specific folder named FTPUSERS, you should use an absolute path to it, such as `E:\FTPUSERS\...` or similar.

Comment: It is [the current working directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory?view=net-8.0).

Answer (score 0):

`@"FTPUSERS\hoz_tbr\from\"` is a **relative** path, so it's evaluated relatively to the current working directory. Seems like you want to have an absolute path, in which case it should strat with the drive name, e.g., `@"C:\FTPUSERS\hoz_tbr\from\"`.